# Tablesorting javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have a table as follows-

```
                          <table class="table">
                              <tbody><tr>
                                <th><h5>Movie</h5></th>
                                <th><h5>test8</h5></th>
                                <th><h5>test5</h5></th>
                                <th><h5>test4</h5></th>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td data-th="Movie Title">Star </td>
                                <td data-th="test">Adci-fi</td>
                                <td data-th="test1">17</td>
                                <td data-th="test2">$65</td>
                              </tr>

                            </tbody></table>
```

Trying to sort the table on page load as well as on click of header.

I am able to sort if table is not generated dynamically using below code-

```
<script>
$(function(){
    // jQuery methods go here...
    $("table.sort_table").sort_table({
        "action" : "init"
    });
});
</script>
```

But when i am trying to do the same when table is generated dynamically on page load this doesn't work .
Please suggest how to proceed.

Comment: How _do_ you try to sort the table (if this is what troubles you)?

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the table in many ways , you can create the own plugin to achieve this aslo. For time savings you can use DataTable plugin or jquery table sorter, bootgrid etc..

for example :

DataTable plugin
https://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/

```
 $('#<table id>').DataTable({

  "order": [[ 5, "desc" ]]});
```

ascendind or descending or you can sorty the table with you can create custom sort also ..

Comment: I am able to sort if table is not generated dynamically using below code-<script>
$(function(){
    // jQuery methods go here...
    $("table.sort_table").sort_table({
        "action" : "init"
    });
});
</script> But when i am tryin to do the same when table is generated dynamically on page load this doesn't work could you please help.

Comment: please post your code clearly, we can able to sort any kind of table :) . I ll help you.

Comment: I am trying to use the approach used in this link-https://github.com/laiconglin/bootstrap3_jquery_table_sortable     ,but i am not able to sort the content  when table is getting created on page load. Following is the code used to sort if table is not created dynamically-<script>
$(function(){
    // jQuery methods go here...
    $("table.sort_table").sort_table({
        "action" : "init"
    });
});
</script>